# IntelliJ compiled class file permissions

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compilation, file-permissions

When I compile files using latest IntelliJ 2016.1.2 Build -> Make module module-name.

This generates class files in Output Path value set in Project Settings.

Class files generated always has -rwxrwx---+ permissions. Then I have to again chmod 644 to change permissions to make this class file readable to everyone.

Is there any way IntelliJ can compile & generate class files with permissions as readable -rw-r--r--

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: No I didn't find a fix